# Accounting: Automatically Sort And Put Timestamp In Right Corner On Invoices I Receive

Tags: taxes, accounting

Whenever I do my taxes I have to collect all my invoices and add the date with a pen in the right corner and then sort them by date, my question is - are there any programs that can help me automate this and do this for me:

- a) Sort my invoices by month and day
- b) Automatically add a timestamp, preferably in color and with a box around it
- c) Has gmail support or an API

Something like a document manager but dedicated to accounting/invoices that can easily import from gmail or outlook

I currently use Quicken, but support for that is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the formats you are using (I'm guessing you receive all types of formats), but would it be possible to save each received invoice to a file with the invoice date (YYYYMMDD) as the first part of the filename e.g. "20131231 blahblah.eml"

Then

- you can just use file sorting if you want to see them onscreen
  sorted.
- you can also save the sorted listing of files in a folder to its
  own file.
- it is a common printing option for software to include the
  filename in the top or bottom margin. (Use a 'Print to PDF'
  application if you want softcopies with this datestamp, instead of
  paper)

As of Dec 2013, Gmail apparently permits you to download/export emails - either to a local email client (via POP) or to a file (but it seems to be text only?).